# Equivalent of numpy.digitize in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am working on a customised loss function that uses `numpy.digitize()` internally. The loss is minimised for a set of parameters that are the `bins` values used in digitize method. In order to use the `tensorflow` optimisers, I would like to know if there an equivalent implementation of `digitize` in `tensorflow`? if not is there a good way to implement a workaround?

Here a numpy version:

```py
def fom_func(b, n):
    np.where((b > 0) & (n > 0), np.sqrt(2*(n*np.log(np.divide(n,b)) + b - n)),0) 
def loss(param, X, y):
    param = np.sort(np.asarray(param))
    nbins = param.shape[0]
    score = 0
    y_pred = np.digitize(X, param)
    for c in np.arange(nbins):
        b = np.where((y==0) & (y_pred==c), 1, 0).sum()
        n = np.where((y_pred==c), 1, 0).sum()
        score += fom_func(b,n)**2
    return -np.sqrt(score)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `np.digitize` method is called `bucketize` in TensorFlow, quoting from [this api doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/bucketize):

> Bucketizes 'input' based on 'boundaries'.
>
> Summary
>
> For example, if the inputs are boundaries = [0, 10, 100] input = [[-5, 10000] [150, 10] [5, 100]]
>
> then the output will be output = [[0, 3] [3, 2] [1, 3]]
>
> Arguments:
>
> scope: A Scope object
>   input: Any shape of Tensor contains with int or float type.
>   boundaries: A sorted list of floats gives the boundary of the buckets.
>   Returns:
>
> Output: Same shape with 'input', each value of input replaced with bucket index.
>   **(numpy) Equivalent to np.digitize.**

I'm not sure why but, this method is hidden in TensorFlow (see the [hidden_ops.txt file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/hidden_ops.txt)). So I wouldn't count on it even if you can import it by doing:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
math_ops._bucketize
```

Comment: The new version of TF calls this `apply_buckets` in TensorflowTransform https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/apply_buckets

Answer (score 0):

this has helped me, you only have to pay attention that the affiliation does not happen to the right or to the left but with regard to the spaces in between the bins:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfp.stats.find_bins()
```