# Calculate segment ids needed in tf.math.segment_sum by length of segments in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working with sequential data of variable-size.
Lets consider data like

```
Y = [ [.01,.02], [.03,.04], [.05,.06], [.07,.08], [.09,.1] ]
l = [ 3, 2 ]
```

where `Y` is the result of some auxiliary calculation performed on my data and `l` stores the length of the original sequences. In this example `[.01,.02], [.03,.04], [.05,.06]` is thus the result of a calculation performed on the first sequence of the batch and `[.07,.08], [.09,.1]` is the result of a calculation performed on the second sequence of the batch of lengths `3`and `2` respectively. 
Now I would like to do some further calculations on the entries of `Y`, but grouped by sequences. In Tensorflow there are functions as `tf.math.segment_sum` which can be performed on a per-group basis.

Lets say I would like to sum using `tf.math.segment_sum`. I would be interested in

```
seq_ids = [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
tf.math.segment_sum(Y, segment_ids=seq_ids) #returns [ [0.09 0.12], [0.16 0.18] ]
```

The problem that I now face is to get `seq_ids` from `l`.
In numpy one would easily retrieve this by

```
seq_ids = np.digitize( np.arange(np.sum(l)), np.cumsum(l) )
```

It seems that there is a hidden (from the python api) equivalent of `digitize` named `bucketize` as mentioned in [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914476/10316642) for a `digitize` in Tensorflow. 
But it seems that the refered `hidden_ops.txt` has been removed from Tensorflow and it is unclear to me if there still is (and will be) support for the function `tensorflow::ops::Bucketize` in the python api.
Another idea I had to get a similar result was to use the `tf.train.piecewise_constant` function. But this attempt failed, as

```
seq_ids = tf.train.piecewise_constant(tf.range(tf.math.reduce_sum(l)), tf.math.cumsum(l), tf.range(BATCH_SIZE-1))
```

failed with `object of type 'Tensor' has no len()`. 
It seems that `tf.train.piecewise_constant` isn't implemented in the most general way as the parameters `boundaries` and `values` need to be lists instead of tensors. As `l` in my case is a 1-D tensor gathered in a minibatch of my `tf.data.Dataset`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_seq_ids(lens):
    # Get accumulated sums (e.g. [2, 3, 1] -> [2, 5, 6])
    c = tf.cumsum(lens)
    # Take all but the last accumulated sum value as indices
    idx = c[:-1]
    # Put ones on every index
    s = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(idx, 1), tf.ones_like(idx), [c[-1]])
    # Use accumulated sums to generate ids for every segment
    return tf.cumsum(s)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(make_seq_ids([2, 3, 1])))
    # [0 0 1 1 1 2]
```

EDIT:

You can also implement the same thing using [`tf.searchsorted`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/searchsorted), in a more similar way to what you proposed for NumPy:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_seq_ids(lens):
    c = tf.cumsum(lens)
    return tf.searchsorted(c, tf.range(c[-1]), side='right')
```

Neither of these implementations should be a bottleneck in a TensorFlow model, so for about any practical purpose it won't matter which one you choose. However, it is interesting to note that, in my particular machine (Win 10, TF 1.12, Core i7 7700K, Titan V), the second implementation is ~1.5x slower when running on CPU and ~3.5x faster when running on GPU.

Comment: This won‘t resolve the problem for people needing a real replacement of digitize. But it fits my specific problem and I find the idea of using scatter_nd to insert increments at the right positions really neat. Thank you!

Comment: @user447457 About digitize, you can look at [Equivalent of numpy.digitize in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48887547/1782792). Apparently the "hidden" op `tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops._bucketize` implements that, but it's not clear to what extent you should rely on operations that are not part of the public API. However, there is [`tf.searchsorted`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/searchsorted), which does largely the same thing. I added an alternative implementation using that.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tf.ragged.row_splits_to_segment_ids` is exactly what you are looking for. You just need `tf.cumsum` to convert length into cumulative length first. This can help you get `seq_ids` from `l`. The code will be like

```
Y = [ [.01,.02], [.03,.04], [.05,.06], [.07,.08], [.09,.1] ]
l = [ 3, 2 ]
l_cum = tf.math.cumsum(l)
l_cum = tf.concat([[0], l_cum], axis=0)
seq_ids = tf.ragged.row_splits_to_segment_ids(l_cum)
tf.math.segment_sum(Y, segment_ids=seq_ids)
```